# Checkout boost from github using SVN

Tags: svn, github, boost

Whenever I try to checkout boost from github using SVN I get the following error:
[image]
[image]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raced a github support ticket. They fixed the issue. The boost repo is now available again by using URL https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git

Answer (score 0):

For accessing with SVN GitHub-based Git-repos URL of repository without trailing `.git` part must be used: SVN can't read Git repos directly, GitHub's gate provide SVN-interface to clients using special additional URL.

But (it can be settings of repository-owner or GitHub glitches), SVN-access to /boostorg/boost repo is broken

```
>svn ls https://github.com/boostorg/boost
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://github.com/boostorg/boost'
svn: E175002: Unexpected HTTP status 500 'Internal Server Error' on '/boostorg/boost'

svn: E175002: Additional errors:
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request on '/boostorg/boost' failed: 500 Internal Server Error
```

While for (at least some) other repositories it work:

for repository with HTTPS-URL `https://github.com/s9y/Serendipity.git`

```
>svn ls https://github.com/s9y/Serendipity
branches/
tags/
trunk/
```

(note, again, URL for SVN-client)